# Equation for circle of curvature for parabola $y=x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the equation for circle of curvature of the parabola $y= x^2$  at $(0,0)$ is

What i try ::  Given $y=x^2$ and $y'=2x$ and $y''=2$.

Then curvature $$K=\frac{y''}{(1+(y')^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{2}{(1+4x^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Put $x=0,$ We get $\displaystyle K=2$, So radius $\displaystyle R=\frac{1}{K}=\frac{1}{2}$

Now i did not understand How can i Find Center of circle in that case.

Also here can we say that equation of Osculating circle is equation of circle. Please helo me. Thanks

Comment: Surely the centre will lie on the $y$-axis?

Comment: And surely your circle will touch the parabola only at $(0,0)$ ?